# Plotting State Border without Water using R and Raster?

Tags: r

Suppose I want to plot New York or Ohio using R:

```
library('ggplot2')
library('map')
library('raster')

map <- raster::getData("GADM",country='USA',level=1)
map <- map[map$NAME_1 %in% c('Ohio'),]
map <- map_data(map)

ggplot() + 
  theme_void() +
  geom_polygon(data = map, 
           aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), 
           fill="grey", alpha=0.3)
```

Here are the results:

[image: New York Plot]

[image: Ohio]

How can I not display extra land in the Ohio plot, and only display land for New York?

It looks like it plots the state borders, see google maps for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to what you are getting for New York, the extra bit in Ohio represents the state border on Lake Erie and might therefore be a property of the GADM data. This approach uses the data from the `maps` package and plots the state borders on land:

```
library('ggplot2')
library('maps')

map <- map_data('state')
ohio <- subset(map, region %in% "ohio")
newyork <- subset(map, region %in% "new york")

ggplot() + 
  theme_void() +
  geom_polygon(data = ohio, 
               aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), 
               fill="grey", alpha=0.3)
ggplot() + 
  theme_void() +
  geom_polygon(data = newyork, 
               aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), 
               fill="grey", alpha=0.3)
```

[image]
[image]